# Can a non-EU citizen with residency visa traveling with me come with me through the EU passport line, when entering Schengen area?

Tags: schengen, borders, customs-and-immigration

I’m doing some travelling with my mate in a few weeks and I was wondering if, to save time, he could come through the Schengen border through the EU Line with me even though he is not a citizen?
I’m a dual Australian and Italian citizen, and he is an Australian citizen and has a 1 year residency visa (Italy).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which queue for a EU/non-EU couple travelling through UK Immigration Control together?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49195/which-queue-for-a-eu-non-eu-couple-travelling-through-uk-immigration-control-tog)

Comment: @JulienLopez  UK is not Schengen - I don't see how it could be a strict duplicate.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Generally not.  Non-EU citizens who are family members of EU citizens within the meaning of the free movement directive are entitled to use the EU passport lines at Schengen borders, but other traveling companions are not (see articles 10(2) and 2(5) of the [Schengen Borders Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02016R0399-20170407)).

You can of course accompany him in the "all passports" queue.  While that won't save any time, it should at least be less boring and/or more convivial.

Comment: The free movement directive only applies when you're entering a country that's not the country of your nationality. I.e. in this case it wouldn't apply to an Italian (and companions) entering Italy. So that can't be the official reason in every situation.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt That's still the definition used in the Schengen Borders code.

Comment: *"Non-EU citizens who are family members of EU citizens within the meaning of the free movement directive are entitled to use the EU passport lines at Schengen borders"* Do you have a reference for this?  It could have saved a lot of time, but I had no idea ...

Comment: Also, if this is possible because of the freedom of movement directive, then it should apply at all EU borders, not just Schengen, right?

Comment: @Szabolcs [Schengen Borders Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02016R0399-20170407), article 10(2), read in the context of the definition at Article 2(5).  Also note 2(6), which excludes non-EU family members covered by the directive from the term "third-country national" for the purpose of the Schengen Borders Code.  The Schengen Borders Code does not apply in the UK or Ireland, and because this rule is established in the SBC, not the directive, the UK and Ireland are not obliged to have a similar rule.  But see the comment I'm about to leave on the other answer.

Comment: @Szabolcs as I understand it, in the UK such a family can go to the EU passports desk because the UK has a policy of not requiring families to separate.  But I haven't ever seen that written anywhere, despite looking.  I have no idea about Ireland.   As to the countries that are officially Schengen candidates, I do not know whether they are bound by this part of the SBC, but I suppose that even if they are not, they follow it in practice.

Comment: @phoog I got told that was the (UK) case before, and then later got told off at a different airport for putting it into practice.

Comment: @Dan that is an obvious problem with unwritten policies.  The US situation seems to be similar; I've been repeatedly and clearly told in New York that a US citizen can bring non-US family to the US citizens' line, while someone else has reported here being repeatedly and clearly told the opposite in Texas.

Answer (score 14):

With a residency visa and accompanied by you it is worth a try, but no guarantees.

I've had this several times in Germany with my girlfriend, who has a non-european citizenship, but a residence permit. The first time we entered Germany together, I stood with her the "all passports" queue and when we finally came to the counter, the officer looked at us and asked why we hadn't gone to the "EU" line. Which after this we did and never had issues.

This may not be official policy, however.

---

Addendum:

[A study](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/329061434_Durable_Relationship_and_Family_Members_by_Analogy_in_the_European_Union) details the differences of member states treatment of unmarried partnerships. For example, about Germany it writes:

*"Germany [...] does not include common spouse partnerships and does therefore not seem to recognise the principle of durable relationship."*

Comment: The difference here of course US that your travel companion was your girlfriend, so possibly entitled to the benefit of the directive, although it's not clear that the officer was aware of that fact or reacting to it. In any event, practice appears to vary by country. I recall reading here about a married couple, where one had EU citizenship and the other did not, being sent to the all-passports desk in Italy after waiting in the EU passports line.

Comment: and had a residence permit

Comment: @akostadinov Official ruling is that people with residence permits must use the all passports queue, except if national law specifies otherwise. See [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52941/can-schengen-resident-permit-holders-use-the-eu-line-at-passport-control). Can't find any information whether that's the case with Germany.

Comment: @phoog no, "girlfriend" is a status with no legal meaning. Marriage is a different thing, legally speaking.

Comment: @akostadinov at that time she had a 1 year visa, just like the person in the question.

Comment: @Tom which part of what I wrote are you saying "no" to?  While "girlfriend" has no legal meaning, the benefits of the free movement directive can also extend to partners in a "durable relationship," and I've known plenty of couples in such relationships who have used the words "girlfriend" and "boyfriend" to refer to each other.

Comment: @phoog If so, how could that be checked? The OP might declare their mate as a durable relationship - who could disprove this?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen a partner in a durable relationship qualifies when the relationship is "duly attested."  Each country sets the standards for that attestation.  The couple would have the burden of proof; nobody would be required to disprove it.  That is why I said "possibly entitled" rather than "entitled."

Comment: @phoog to the "difference" part. I've lived all my life in Germany and I'm not aware that there is any kind of legal recognition of "girlfriend" as a status. To the law, "girlfriend" and "stranger" are synonyms.  https://www.toytowngermany.com/forum/topic/273824-german-and-american-unmarried-partnership/ specifically mentions that "Germany does not recognize unmarried partners" - which matches my experience. I've also added a link to a study into the answer.

Comment: I do not know how relevant it is to the question of Schengen border control, but to German law there exist things like "nichteheliche Lebensgemeinschaft" and "eheähnliche Gemeinschaft" which is basically non-married couples. There are certain rights that come with that status, however.

Comment: @kap the first is an official status that you need to register for. It's basically the gay marriage that they didn't want to call marriage for not upsetting the church. The 2nd comes into play in custody questions and such, but it would be news to me that it matters at the border.

Comment: @kap, Tom, Germany's refusal to implement the directive fully with respect to unmarried, unregistered "durable partners" has apparently been well noted by the commission.  See for example https://www.migrationsrecht.net/nachrichten-gesetzgebung-auslaenderrecht/geplante-aenderung-des-freizuegg-eu-mit-unionsrecht-unzureichend.html

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that a bit of common sense is applied for people travelling together and they will let you both through in the shortest queue. This also assists when they as for reason for visit etc. This applies when I've been going into UK, Thailand, and France.

Answer (score 0):

There's also a different security aspect - I (UK citizen) was told off for not bringing my wife (then only ILR) through the UK&EU queue because I was sitting on the seats beyond immigration - I got the impression that they don't like people waiting there in case they are spying on how the process works.